# Going backwards select the first non negative number SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, do-loops

I have a dataset that looks similar to the below:

```
ID  COL70  COL71 COL72 COL73 COL74
1     4      3     2    -998   .
2     2      0     2      1   -998
3     1     -998  -998    .    .
4     3      4    -998  -998  -998
```

What I want to do is have a new columns lets call it NEWCOL that has the first non negative value looking backwards from COL74, so it would look as follows:

```
ID  COL70  COL71 COL72 COL73 COL74  NEWCOL
1     4      3     2    -998   .      2 
2     2      0     2      1   -998    1 
3     1     -998  -998    .    .      1
4     3      4    -998  -998  -998    4
```

I'm working from WPS so this would need to be in SAS or PROC SQL please.

Comment: Please include anything you've tried in your questions.

Comment: @Reeza I didn't know where to start so I hadn't tried anything before hand. That's why I posted the question. I didn't realise I had to have tried something to be able to post a question?

Comment: Does anyone know why the question's been down voted? I'm looking to improve the way I ask questions if I've done anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: Most likely because you haven't shown any attempt. Yes, you're supposed to have attempted to solve the problem first yourself in some manner. Please see the guidelines on how to ask a question [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the response @Reeza , I'll try and post links to questions that haven't solved the problem in the future as sometimes I have no idea where to start and that's why I post the question. But I'll try and include questions that don't quite fit what I need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over an array like this.

```
data have;
   array c[*] col70-col74;
   input id c[*];
   do i = dim(c) to 1 by -1 until(sign(c[i]) eq 1); 
      newcol=c[i]; 
      end;
   if i eq 0 then newcol=.;
   cards;
1     4      3     2    -998   .
2     2      0     2      1   -998
3     1     -998  -998    .    .
4     3      4    -998  -998  -998
5     -3     -4    -998  -998  -998
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone wanting the same:

```
data want;
set have;
temp = 0;
num = 74;
array col{70:74} col70-col74;
do while (temp = 0);
if col{num} >= 0 then do;
newvar = col{num};
temp = 1;
end;
else num = num - 1;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL a simple `case` expression can 'backup' to the desired result

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select have.*
  ,
  case
    when col74 > 0 then col74
    when col73 > 0 then col73
    when col72 > 0 then col72
    when col71 > 0 then col71
    when col70 > 0 then col70
    else .
  end as last_positive
  from have
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: The question holds only a subset of the actual dataset, I have over 104 columns in total so doing a case when for 104 columns wouldn't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work ? The SQL case statement has no limitation.  If need be you can write a macro to generate the necessary `when` clauses.  An actual problem having > 104 similar columns sounds like your data model has 2 years of weekly data as columns and that might be hindering coding up cleaner time-dimensional analysis or updating the table(s) with next weeks data.  SQL does not have arrays so SQL select is coded with the wallpaper `case`.

Comment: I need to keep all columns for business reasons. It wouldn't work for me as I don't think it's best practice to code up case when over a 100 times?